# How to configure routes for different user models using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-routing

I have two different user groups, User and Flyer.

I have generated views and controllers for both the models using,

```
rails g devise:controllers users/flyers
```

and for views:

```
rails g devise:views users/flyers
```

This is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :flyers
  devise_for :admins
  resources :currencies
  resources :broadcasts

  devise_for :users, controllers: {
        sessions: 'users/sessions',
            registrations: 'flyers/registrations'

      }

  devise_for :flyers, controllers: {
    sessions: 'flyers/sessions',
  }
end
```

But I am getting error for devise for flyers controllers route:

```
Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_flyer_session' You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created
```

How can I have different routes?
Thanks

Comment: @RaviMariya add this as answer..I will tag it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `devise_for :flyers` from top